# Как в Андроид Студио реализовать возможность включения ночного режима всего (разрабатываемого) приложения?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ui

Очень просят некоторые пользователи реализовать такую возможность в приложении для работы с ним ночью.

Порой, очень сильно просят) ... Я им советую яркость убавлять, говорят, "не очень вариант..." )

Речь идет об образовательном Андроид приложении

P.S.
Ситуация такая, меня просят пользователи, чтобы в приложении можно было ночью включать некий ночной режим просмотра... Видимо, включать какой-то "общепринятый" ночной режим с меньшей освещенностью (некий ночной стиль)

Comment: В своем университете я обращался за советом к опытным разработчикам в области программирования под Андроид... Они не смогли навскидку мне ничего посоветовать такого, чтобы решало эту задачу сразу для всего приложения. Поэтому я задал этот вопрос здесь. А про деньги я сообщил только в контексте, что некоторые очень хотят такой функционал, даже за отд. плату... ) P.S. Лично я под Андроид пишу совсем недолго...

Comment: user, на Вашем месте посоветовал бы Вашим пользователям установить программу [**Red Moon**](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.jmstudios.redmoon/). **1.** Open Source, **2.** Ночной режим можно включить для всех программ, не надо каждый раз просить сделать для какой-то конкретной. **3.** Кастомные настройки ночного режима. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Поддержка такой  темы [появилась с support library 23.2.0](https://www.journaldev.com/19352/android-daynight-theme-night-mode). все реализуется довольно просто.

Comment: Огромное спасибо Pavlofff!